# Amplify voltage between transistors in a current mirror setup?

Tags: transistors

I have a bottom gate TFT transistor:

- W/l=320um
- Substrate: corning glass
- Gate: 60nm Molibdenum
- Dielectric: 350 nm Ta2O5
- Semiconductor: 30nm IGZO
- S-D: Molibdenum 60nm

It is wired like in current mirror setup https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_mirror#Basic_MOSFET_current_mirror :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f34hBc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am forcing pulses of current IDS and registering VGS=VDS
This is what it looks like on the SMU:

- Plot 1: CH1 IDS VS time
- Plot 2: Ch1 VGS vs time

[image: Plots]

I want to wire a second transistor in the same way, get a recording VGS2 and then find the difference VGS1-VGS2.

### The application

I am using the TFT to detect ionizing radiation: The X-ray radiation creates electron-hole pairs in the dielectric, which then affects the VGS recorded for a fixed ISD

Here is a plot showing how the VGS curve changes with the radiation exposure:

[image: VGS vs Time]

### EDIT-from remices2 answer

Does the circuit in the answer of remicles2 work? Since it has only gotten down votes for now, but I think because it wasn't using my original circuit (which I edited now since I think it was my circuit that was wrong.)

Comment: This is quite broad, I suggest you study circuits with transistors and figure out how they work. Also "TFT transistors" are quite uncommon unless they are in an LCD.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is a transimpedance amplifier (google this).

Comment: What type of transistors are these? This isn't really a common mode of operation if I'm understanding what you're doing.

Comment: TFT is "thin film transistor" typically used in LCD displays with transistors at each pixel position. The materials used to produce the MOSFETs in displays are transparent so that light can pass through. It is possible that @leoelectrics is trying to work with some other TFT's that are designed for some other application. It would be suggested that they describe more what the goal is.

Comment: @Captainj2001 The transimpedance amplifier seems to need a current input, while I want to input Voltage.

Comment: @leoelectrics I think that an instrumentation amplifier works if it needs to be a hardware solution. I'd prefer to do this with an ADC and software probably since time is on the order of miliseconds.

Comment: You are trying to **force** a drain current and measure the resulting gate voltage? That sounds completely backwards to me. I don't see how it can work.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I am using the TFT backwards, but as you can see from the last plot (real data) it is working well for radiation detection. Does the circuit I show not work? maybe I am drawing it wrong?

Comment: @Captainj2001 Ideally it would be hardware, would be useful to have a single readout point. I have added a circuit I think might work, does it look alright?

Comment: I don't think you can force dc current into the drain and expect the gate voltage to rise to the threshold voltage. The normal technique is to vary \$V_{GS}\$ for some constant \$V_{DS}\$ and measure \$I_{DS}\$.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson The experiment has already been done, we passed dc current and read VGS, those plots are from real data. Maybe I am still missing something in my circuit drawing

Comment: Your schematic has no ground reference. Exactly how are you forcing current into the Drains, and how did you measure the Gate voltage on a single FET?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, you can indeed run a MOSFET "backwards" and get a \$V_{GS}\$ from a fixed drain current.  That's the essence of building a MOSFET current mirror: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_mirror#Basic_MOSFET_current_mirror

Comment: @remicles2 The current mirror requires that the gate of the driven transistor be connected **to its drain**. The circuit proposed by the OP has no such connection...completely different situation.

Comment: @remicles2 the current mirror link looks like a description of what I am looking for

Comment: "Does the circuit in the answer of remicles2 work?"  I can't answer that for certain without duplicating your experimental setup and doing the experiment for you.  If you are able to generate two different voltages, then a differential op-amp configuration (the right hand side of my schematic) will amplify the voltage difference for you.  That should be sufficient to answer your original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical way of amplifying the difference between two voltages is with an op-amp configuration known as a "differential amplifier".  A basic explanation is here:
http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Electronic/opampvar6.html

More information can be found on Wikipedia or in a circuits textbook.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_amplifier

To add a differential amplifier to your circuit, I would first connect the source of each transistor to ground so they have the same \$V_S\$, the drain of each to its own identical current source, and connect the gates to the drain terminals (so that \$V_{GS}=V_{DS}\$, which will be determined by (1) the transistor geometry and materials, (2) the current source, and most importantly, (3) the radiation applied).  This is called a "diode" connection, but I believe it is what you have already built and measured, or will at least will work the same way.  I may be wrong here.  From here, you can connect the two gates to the inputs of the differential amplifier.  This schematic might be a good start (don't pay much attention to the component values, they're just placeholders):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXgJP0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Two comments on your schematic diagrams, since they are unclear.  First, your N-channel MOSFETs are mislabeled.  You have swapped the source and drain terminals.  Second, the wires in your schematic connect to an odd portion of the MOSFET symbol.  See this picture for reference:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSFET#/media/File:IGFET_N-Ch_Enh_Labelled.svg
A schematic should only connect to the terminals of the MOSFET outside of the circled portion.

This is a cool application of a TFT, by the way.

EDIT:

The circuit I posted is very similar to a PTAT temperature sensor.  Figure 4 at https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/chip-to-monitor-environmental-conditions-on-motherboard.html# provides a clear example:

[image: BJT PTAT temperature sensor]

In a PTAT sensor, either the two current sources are different, or they are the same and the transistor geometries are different.  This causes the two \$V_{BE}\$ voltages to respond differently with temperature changes.  Measuring this voltage difference allows you to calculate the absolute temperature.  If you can understand this principle, then you can see how your TFT radiation sensor works similarly.  Now that I think about it, I would be concerned that your voltage measurements at a fixed radiation exposure will also change with temperature.  You should confirm with environmental testing experiments.

Comment: What makes you think that the OP intended to connect the transistor gates to their drains? In both of the OP's schematics the gates are not connected to the drain, or to any source of current.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson As I didn't setup the experiment, I probably remember it wrong, my bad. I think remicles2's solution with the drain and Gate shorted and the source set to ground is probably what they did. 
Can this circuit be simulated now with 2 different transistors to see that it actually is reading the VDS1-VDS2?

Comment: @remicles, following your advice, I have updated circuit1, I am not sure I am connecting the voltmeter correctly, does it have to be connected between VGD or VGS and VGD just shorted?

Comment: @leoelectrics The voltmeter is connected to the correct terminals of the MOSFET, but the polarity is backwards.  You want to measure between the Source and the Gate to get \$V_{GS}\$ which is equal to \$V_{DS}\$ in this circuit. In your updated schematic, the negative lead of the meter is connected to the Gate, but should be connected to the Source.  That's not a huge problem, but you should know that a positive \$V_{GS}\$ will look like a negative voltage on that meter as it is currently connected.

Comment: @leoelectrics In general, schematics are easier to understand if you draw them with higher voltages on top, and lower voltages at the bottom of the drawing, so that current flows from top to bottom (towards "ground" to use that metaphor).  It's also good to put inputs to the circuit on the left, and draw the schematics so outputs are on the right.  Following this advice, your NMOSFET is upside down, as is the ground symbol on it's gate.  You can also flip the MOSFET so the gate is on the left.  Doing that will make it easier to connect the voltmeter symbol correctly.

Comment: @leoelectrics I don't have any experience using CircuitLab for simulation, but you should be able to change transistor properties and see a difference between VDS1 and VDS2.

Comment: ok thanks, last thing I don't understand, why did you connect and ideal voltage source before the 2 ideal current sources, what is the use of it? Can't the with only the ideal current source

Comment: Good catch.  You are right, it is redundant.  You can replace the ideal voltage source with a wire to get the same effect.  I put it in there just because most real current sources need a source of power, but of course, an ideal current source is its own source of power.

Comment: I guess it's a habit from my circuits textbook, which has lots of diagrams like the one in this post that include an ideal current source in series with a voltage source:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/377804/do-we-have-a-voltage-drop-across-this-ideal-current-source

Comment: Ok, thanks, by my understanding this setup works!

Comment: An in-amp might be a better idea than a plain op-amp here, since that way you can avoid loading the circuit being measured.

Comment: Certainly, but I don't really know what the input impedance requirements are, so I didn't mention it.  @leoelectrics Look into instrumentation amplifiers if you find you need a high performance differential amplifier.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentation_amplifier

Comment: @Hearth I've added the impedence measurement of the TFT, would this still work with the opamp setup ?

Comment: remicles2, Interesting point the one about temperature, I would need to do some tests. One of the reasons for getting the voltage difference between 2 transistors is that if I expose one to radiation, and one not, then their difference should just be due to radiation, eliminating Tdiff, etc.

Comment: That assumes that the radiation response is independent of absolute temperature, and I don't know if that's a safe assumption.

Comment: There's a joke that "all sensors are temperature sensors, but some are better than others".

Comment: I don't see the impedance measurements you mention, but after some quick LTSpice simulations (with a diode connected NMOS in parallel with 300kOhm like in my example schematic), I'd agree with @Hearth that an instrumentation amp would be a good idea.  It really depends on the actual device characteristics and your accuracy requirements though.